# Formatting dates in different locales

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date value in cell `A1` and in `A2` I am converting this to show only its month name with `TEXT` formula. My locale is Turkish but need to show the month in English. Come up with below formula which works fine on my computer.

But when this Excel file is opened at a computer with English locale, the user sees "**aaaa**" in the cell because in English locale, month formatting string is "**mmmm**" but not "**aaaa**". When I change the string to "**mmmm**", then I will not able to see the month but "**mmmm**" string instead.

Is there any pure-formula method to overcome this problem?

```
TEXT(A1,"[$-en-EN]aaaa")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better method, but this one worked for me:

```
=TEXT(A1,IF(TEXT("1/1/2018","[$-en-EN]aaaa")="January","[$-en-EN]aaaa","[$-en-EN]mmmm"))
```

Comment: Wow, a very nice way indeed! :) This is resolving my problem since I am only dealing with two locales. I will accept it as answer as soon as I get sure that there is no other generic method which may cope with all possible locales (not involving nested `IF`s of course :) )